# Rewrite html5 page in JSF page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I have html5 which I want to rewrite into JSF page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=1,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=1" />
        <title>Insert title here</title>

        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100italic,100,300italic,300,400italic,400,700italic,700,900italic,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/styles.css" />
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <section class="container login-form">
            <section>
                <form method="post" action="" role="login">
                    <img src="logo.png" alt="" class="img-responsive" />

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" name="email" required="true" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="password" name="password" required="true" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Forgot password ?">?</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" name="go" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login Now</button>
                </form>
            </section>
        </section>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

I tried this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:j="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=1,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=1" />
        <title>Insert title here</title>

        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100italic,100,300italic,300,400italic,400,700italic,700,900italic,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/styles.css" />
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <section class="container login-form">
            <section>
                <h:form>
                    <img src=logo.png" alt="" class="img-responsive" />

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h:inputText j:type="email" j:name="email" required="true" styleClass="form-control" j:placeholder="Email address" value="#{login.user}"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <h:inputSecret j:type="password" j:name="password" required="true" styleClass="form-control" j:placeholder="Password" value="#{login.password}" autocomplete="off"/>
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Forgot password ?">?</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <h:commandButton type="submit" j:name="go" styleClass="btn btn-primary btn-block" action="#{login.userAuthanticate}">Login Now</h:commandButton>
                </h:form>
            </section>
        </section>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

I added `xmlns:j="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"` becasue I want to use html5. When I add `h:form` css style is totally messed up. What is the proper way to rewrite this page in JSF tags?

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/styles.css" />
```

For this:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css" />
```

where `library` is the name of the folder inside `resources` and `name` the file name.

Is possible that the `<h:inputSecret>` will do not render properly with the span inside. If it's the case, then use plain HTML instead.

```
<input type="password" jsf:id="pass" name="password" 
            class="form-control" placeholder="Password..."
            required="">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button id="tooltip" class="btn btn-default" type="button"
                data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
                title="Forgot password?"</button>
    </span>
</input>
```

*PS: Facelets are HTML5 compatible, so, use the HTML5 doctype.*